# How do I update VMs in place with new image versions in ARM?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

If I deploy VM from my own image and I iterate and deploy new version number of image, how do I in place upgrade VM which is already deployed. I can not make those properties AFAIK, so I would not be able to use ARM on it's own to perform this operation and would require complex logic to first check if deployed image is correct version, and if it's not then delete VM and submit new ARM deployment afterwards. Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

I end up with just using Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets with instance count of 1 and disabling "overprovision" feature, this way I always have 1 instance running at a time and it's allows to `update` image.